# Issue with Charset encoding in springbatch if context is stored in Database

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using SpringBatch with JDBC for storing the Job Context and facing an issue Serializing non ascii characters. Looks like 'JdbcExecutionContextDao' class has Character encoding set to 'ISO-8859-1'. Is there anyway to specify encoding as 'UTF-8'

Comment: You can use your own serializer if you want.  The goal of that encoding is really just so that it's symmetrical in and out.

Comment: I've a custom class implementing 'ExecutionContextSerializer' overriding serialize and deserialize methods. I'm trying to convert the map to xml using jaxb and store and the context. By default, the Marshaller seems to use UTF-8 encoding when generating XML data to a java.io.OutputStream (ByteArrayOutputStream is received from spring batch framework) and spring batch is using 'Latin-1' charset to convert ByteArray to String. I hope because of this some unicode and non-latin-1 characters are not encoded correctly. Please let me know if i'm missing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Spring Batch 4.1.1. I was to lazy to write my own ExecutionContextSerializer from scratch. I just converted the bytestream to ISO-8859-1 and used it in my BatchConfig:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() {

        try {
            return jobExplorerFactoryBean();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() {

        try {
            return jobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private JobRepository jobRepositoryFactoryBean() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean fb = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        fb.setSerializer(getContextSerializer());
        fb.setDataSource(getYourDataSource());
        fb.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return fb.getObject();
    }


    private JobExplorer jobExplorerFactoryBean() throws Exception {
        JobExplorerFactoryBean fb = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        fb.setSerializer(getContextSerializer());
        fb.setJdbcOperations(new JdbcTemplate(getYourDataSource()));
        return fb.getObject();
    }

    private ExecutionContextSerializer getContextSerializer(){
        return new LatinJacksonExecutionContextSerializer();        
    }
}


import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class LatinJacksonExecutionContextSerializer extends Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String, Object> context, OutputStream out) throws IOException {

        super.serialize(context, out);
        if (out instanceof ByteArrayOutputStream){
            try {

                //Convert to ISO-8859-1 byteStream, because JDBC ExecutionContextDao expect that
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = (ByteArrayOutputStream) out;
                byte[] bytesUtf8 = baos.toByteArray();
                byte[] latin1 = new String(bytesUtf8, "UTF-8").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                baos.reset();
                //Convert to ByteArrayOutputStream
                ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(latin1);
                IOUtils.copy(in, out);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is that, set `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=NEVER` and modify the schema encoding, so i can use `flyway` to initialize it.

Also，you can change the schema location `spring.batch.jdbc.schema=<your path>`.